# Prove $C(E)$ is a Banach space with E a compact topological space

Tags: real-analysis

Let be E a compact topologycal space. I know that $C(E)\subset B(E)$ with $C(E)=\{f:E\rightarrow \mathbb C \quad$continuous$\}$ and $B(E)=\{f: E\rightarrow \mathbb C \quad$continuous and bounded$ \}$.

$B(E)$ is a Banach space so $C(E)$ is a Banach space because subset of a Banach space?

Comment: Subset of a Banach space is not necessarily a Banach space.

Comment: and if is it a closed subset?

Comment: Yes, if it is a closed sub-vector space, then the induced norm gives it a Banach space structure. However, usually it should be $B(E) \subseteq C(E)$. And in your case, since $E$ is compact, any continuous function is necessarily bounded, hence one has $B(E) = C(E)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify, without too many difficulties, that $C(E)$ is a vector space (just like $B(E)$), according to the [definition of vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition). Furthermore, with the supremum norm, $C(E)$ is also a [normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Normed_vector_spaces_and_inner_product_spaces) (as $B(E)$). As $\mathbb{C}$ is a Banach space, with the norm sup $C(E)$ it is also a Banach space (just like $B(E)$ is also).

In addition, you can prove the following proposition (with a 3-$\epsilon$ argument, like [in tis post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396886/epsilon-3-proof-for-converging-sequence-of-functions)):

***Proposition***. The $B(E)$ space is a closed subspace of $C(E)$, that is, the uniform limit of continuous bounded functions is continuous.

As the E space is compact, so the reciprocal of the proposition is valid, in the sense that we also have $C(E)\subset B(E)$.